# What unlockable items exist in Shower With Your Dad Simulator's main game mode?

Tags: shower-with-dad-simulator

In the main game mode, you can unlock items such as a Razor and Soap. What other items can you unlock, how do you unlock them, and what do they do?

Comment: This is not a game I'd be willing to think of.

Comment: Ha I'm sorry, but I'd be surprised if questions about this game will be answered.

Comment: Unlockables in a game includes the game modes you unlocked.. You probably would have been better clarifying both into the same question, instead of asking two separate ones.

Comment: @Timelord64 Possible. I don't know enough about the game to understand the methods of acquisition. If they're grossly different between game modes (or there's a lot of unlockables), then it might make sense to have different questions.

Comment: To be fair, asking what all the unlockables are, how they are all unlocked *and* what they all do could still easily be considered too broad..

Comment: For the love of all that is holy, please don't find out what dropping the Soap does after unlocking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soap - Double points

Razor - removes hair

Duck - Lower penalties

Beer - Slows time, blurs and shakes screen, keeps the kid slowly moving when 
you stop controlling it

Adoption papers? - Your dad is now signified with an arrow, and is different than your kid would otherwise tell you

Mask - everyone is your dad, but time remaining in the powerup is not shown.

Those are all I have seen, but there could be more.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a Halloween Mask which changes the background to a wooden building and all the dads wear costumes; they're all your dads during this.

Beer slows down time and wobbles your screen a bit.

Comment: Thanks. I think this answer would be best if it were a list of unlockables, though, including the ones I listed. I'll accept it for now.